# udev keyboard remapping with hwdb for secondary keyboards

Tags: keyboard, udev

I have a laptop, and I save the following to `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-custom-keyboard.hwdb`

```
keyboard:usb:v*p*
keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn*:pn*:pvr*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_1a=a
 KEYBOARD_KEY_1b=b
```

and run

```
$ sudo udevadm hwdb --update && sudo udevadm trigger
```

in order to refresh the key mappings.

Now, this is a dummy case that should replace the <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys with <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> for any USB or dmi keyboard. However, I only get the changes on my laptop's keyboard, and not my other keyboards (a wired and another wireless USB keyboard). I am sure that the same scancodes are sent for all the keyboards I have, regarding the keys I want to remap.

I am using Arch Linux and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) is the tutorial I have been looking at.

What do I need to do to make the remapping valid for all USB keyboards that are to be plugged in in the future?

Answer (score 1):

The scancodes for usb keyboards are not what you would expect, they are not the output of `showkey -s`. Instead you pretty much have to use `evtest` to get the scancodes you need.

Example output from `evtest`:

```
Event: time 1399420905.069693, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70004
Event: time 1399420905.069693, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 1
Event: time 1399420905.069693, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

You want the value after `MSC_SCAN`, in this case it tells us the button mapped to the <kbd>A</kbd> key (`KEY_A`) has a scancode of `70004`.