# udev keyboard remapping with hwdb NumLock 0

Tags: keyboard, udev

I have a Samsung np870z5e laptop with builtin Numpad with ubuntu 16.04 and udev 229.

I have a 'Fn-lock' button, if I press it, the Numpad 0 button (KP_0) becomes 'Menu' button (xev reports it), or 'KEY_COMPOSE' (evtest reports it).

So I would like to permanently rewrite KEY_COMPOSE to KP_0. So even if I press FN-lock button on the keyboard the numpad's 0 key should stay 0 key.
(no other key swaps, only the 0 key is problematic).

The keyboard is at:

```
/dev/input/event3
/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd

$ udevadm info /dev/input/by-path/plat*
P: /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3
N: input/event3
S: input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
E: BACKSPACE=guess
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event3
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_PATH=platform-i8042-serio-0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-i8042-serio-0
E: ID_SERIAL=noserial
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_74=prog1
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_75=www
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_78=mail
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_82=!switchvideomode
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_83=!battery
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_84=!prog1
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_86=!wlan
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_88=!brightnessup
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_89=!brightnessdown
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_96=!kbdillumup
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_97=!kbdillumdown
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_b1=!prog2
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_b3=!prog3
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_b4=!wlan
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_c5=!prog3
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_ce=!prog1
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_d5=!wlan
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_f7=!f22
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_f9=!f23
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=67
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1876095
E: XKBLAYOUT=hu
E: XKBMODEL=pc105
```

evtest output:

```
 sudo evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Power Button
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event5:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event6:  ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad
/dev/input/event7:  WebCam SC-10HDP12631N
/dev/input/event8:  HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event9:  HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
Select the device event number [0-10]: 3
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x1 product 0x1 version 0xab41
Input device name: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    Event code 2 (KEY_1)
    Event code 3 (KEY_2)
    ... (truncated for brevity)
```

So the `bus` should be: 0011, `vendor` should be 0x0001:

The hwdb file is this:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/10-my-modifiers.hw 
evdev:input:b0011v0001*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_3a=leftalt     # bind capslock to leftalt
 KEYBOARD_KEY_38=leftctrl    # bind leftalt to leftctrl
 KEYBOARD_KEY_1a=a
 KEYBOARD_KEY_1b=b
```

updated via:

```
$ sudo udevadm hwdb --update && sudo udevadm trigger
```

But it does not work. I also tried with `evdev:name:`, `evdev:atkbd:`, still no luck.

How can I determine what is the correct `evdev:input:b0011v0001*` line?

Similar questions (none is working for me):
[udev keyboard remapping with hwdb for secondary keyboards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197729/udev-keyboard-remapping-with-hwdb-for-secondary-keyboards)
[Udev hwdb rule does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216722/udev-hwdb-rule-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn*:pn*:pvr*
```

On my Thinkpad x240 on Ubuntu 16.04 it works fine:

```
cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-ThinkPad-X240-keyboard.hwdb
# ThinkPad X240: switch End and Insert keys (so that when Fn-Lock is enabled, End works without Fn).
#keyboard:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnLENOVO:pn*:pvrThinkPadX240:*
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnLENOVO:pn*:pvrThinkPadX240:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_d2=end
 KEYBOARD_KEY_cf=insert
```